# Помогите спроектировать программу. Не могу сделать код логически правильным

Tags: c#, winforms

В общем есть класс, назовем его FTP, в нем методы ConnectFTP, CompareFiles и Download Files и форма которая вызывает метод ConnectFTP по нажатию кнопки. Этот метод, который вызывает кнопка из формы, вызывает другой метод CompareFiles, который потом вызывает DownloadFiles. Мне кажется этот код, который я написал, отвратительным, но я хочу придерживаться этих трех методов. Первое что мне бросается в глаза - это то, что я вызываю скачивание через "ConnectFTP". Это не отражает сути, но я не знаю как это правильно спроектировать. Нужно запускать из формы например так `DownloadFiles();` и чтобы этот метод вызвал в начале ConnectFTP, потом CompareFiles и только потом начал выполняться сам. Прошу обратить внимание на то, что методы асинхронные) Если это важно.

Comment: в этом коде от ооп только класс)))

Comment: а мне кажется, что скачивание файлов и сравнение файлов - это разные обязанности и должны быть выполнены разными классами. Смотрите S в SOLID.

Comment: У меня чтобы скачать файлы обязательно должно выполниться сравнение. Оно сравнивает файл который потенциально должен скачаться с файлом который уже был установлен, и если они одинаковые, то этот файл не скачивается. Мне кажется, что все тут нормально, но я не уверен. Ведь задача класса подкачать файлы, которых нет или которые не равны. Хотя я подумаю над этим и лучше внимательней почитаю солид. И это так и не решает моей проблемы.

Comment: то есть у вас должен быть класс, который скачивает. Класс, который сравнивает. И класс, который изпользует первые два класса и содержит вашу логику.

Comment: `И это так и не решает моей проблемы` Вы какое решение ожидаете увидеть?

Comment: А где код то???

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую разбить на 3 класса.